# How to update my Chrome Extension's tooltip or description?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm curious if I can update the tooltip for my Chrome Extension from JS while the app is already running?

Or, what is set up in the manifest.json file in the `description` parameter, or the one that's displayed at mouse-over event over my app's icon:

[image]

PS. That is not my actual app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the docs for [`browserAction` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction):

> [`chrome.browserAction.setTitle(object details)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setTitle)
>
> Sets the title of the browser action. This shows up in the tooltip.

Invocation:

```
chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: "My New Title"});
```

You can optionally limit this update to a particular `tabId`.

P.S. In the manifest, this is normally set by `browser_action.default_title`.